# Why do I get a "no operator found" error when overriding the stream insertion operator in this situation?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a project with multiple header and source files, which I have shortened to what I believe is important here (though I could be wrong). They look like so:

A.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once
struct date_t {
    unsigned int day{ 0 };
    unsigned int month{ 0 };
    unsigned int year{ 0 };
};
```

A.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"
using namespace std;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const date_t& date) {
    output << date.month << "/" << date.day << "/" << date.year;
    return output;
}
```

B.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "A.hpp"
class B {
public:
    date_t date;
};
```

B.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "B.hpp"
using namespace std;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, B& b) {
    output << b.date;
    return output;
}
```

In this particular case, B.cpp gives the error `no operator "<<" matches these operands; operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << date_t`. I'm not quite sure whether or not I need to change the parameters in the overloaded function or if this is an access problem, so why is this error being thrown here? To follow that up, would class B have a similar issue if it's insertion overload was used too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `operator<<` in A.cpp but you need to declare it in a header file too, so code in other cpp files knows about it.

Just add

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const date_t& date);
```

to A.hpp (after the definition of `struct date_t`). You will need to add `#include <iostream>` to A.hpp as well.

Do the same thing with the other insertion operator.

Any function or operator that you define in one cpp file but wish to use in another cpp file should be declared in a header file.